# ACF field as a woocommerce price is not recalculated when the currency changes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I created ACF text field "akcni_cena" which a use as a special price and it is something like the second sale price. I need to this acf field to recalculate when currency change. It doesn' work now.
The other prices like wc_get_price_excluding_tax or wc_get_price_including_tax are normally recalculating when currency change.

```
<?php 
global $product;
$price_excl_tax = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product ); // price without VAT
$price_incl_tax = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );  // price with VAT
$symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
$regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
$akcni_nabidka = get_field('akcni_nabidka');
$akcni_nabidka_on = $akcni_nabidka == true;
$akcni_cena = get_field('akcni_cena');
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$today_time = strtotime($today);
$end_time = strtotime(get_field('ukonceni_akcni_nabidky'));

if( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) {
if ($akcni_cena && $akcni_nabidka_on && $end_time > $today_time) {
    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {

        /* Přeškrtnutá zlevněná cena */
        echo '<div class="strikethrough"> <span class="regprice">' . number_format($regular_price) . $symbol . '</span>' . number_format($price_incl_tax) . ' ' . $symbol . ' <span class="vat">s DPH</span> <br>' . 
            number_format($price_excl_tax) . ' ' . $symbol . ' <span class="vat">bez DPH</span> </div>';
    } else {

        /* Přeškrtnutá normální cena */
        echo  '<div class="strikethrough"> </span>' . wc_price($price_incl_tax) . ' ' .     $symbol . ' <span class="vat">s DPH</span> <br>' . 
        wc_price($price_excl_tax) . ' ' . $symbol . ' <span class="vat">bez DPH</span> </div>';
    }

    /* Akční cena */
        echo 'Akční cena: ' . number_format($akcni_cena) . ' ' . $symbol . ' <span class="vat">s DPH</span>' ;

} else {

    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {

        /* Zlevněná cena */
        echo '<span class="regprice strikethrough">' . number_format($regular_price) . ' ' . $symbol . '<span class="vat"> s DPH</span> </span>' . number_format($price_incl_tax) . ' ' . $symbol . ' <span class="vat">s DPH</span> <br>' . 
            number_format($price_excl_tax) . ' ' . $symbol . ' <span class="vat">bez DPH</span>';
    } else {

        /* Normální cena */
        echo number_format($price_incl_tax) . ' ' .     $symbol . ' <span class="vat">s DPH</span> <br>' . 
        number_format($price_excl_tax) . ' ' . $symbol . ' <span class="vat">bez DPH</span>';
    }
}
}elseif($product->is_type('variable')) {
$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();    
$variation_product_id = $product_variations[0]['variation_id'];
$variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_product_id );
$variation_product_price = $variation_product ->regular_price;
$variation_prodct_sale_price = $variation_product ->sale_price;
$variable_price = $product->get_price();
if ($akcni_cena && $akcni_nabidka_on && $end_time > $today_time) {
    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        
        /* Přeškrtnutá zlevněná cena */
        echo '<span class="regprice strikethrough">' . number_format($variation_product_price) . ' ' . $symbol . '</span> <br> <span>' . number_format($variation_prodct_sale_price) . ' ' . $symbol . '</span>';
    } else {
        
        /* Přeškrtnutá normální cena */
        echo  '<div class="regprice strikethrough">' . number_format( $variation_product_price) . ' ' . $symbol . '</div>';
    }
        
        /* Akční cena */
        echo 'Akční cena: ' . number_format($akcni_cena) . ' ' . $symbol . '<span class="vat"> s DPH</span>' ;
    
}else {

    if( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
            
        /* Zlevněná cena */
        echo '<span class="regprice strikethrough">' . number_format($variation_product_price) . ' ' . $symbol . '</span> <br> <span>' . number_format($variation_prodct_sale_price) . ' ' . $symbol . '</span>';
    } else {
            
        /* Normální cena */
        echo  '<span>' . number_format($variation_product_price) . ' ' . $symbol . '</span>';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: which pluign are you using for currency change?

Comment: Hi. I am using the CURCY - Multi Currency for WooCommerce plugin.

Comment: so try `$akcni_cena = wmc_get_price(get_field('akcni_cena'));`